# EMA computation using filter function in R

Tags: r, vector, filtering

I would like to reproduce this code in vectorized notation

```
getEMA2<-function(x,win){
k<-2/(win+1)
v<-vector()
for (i in 1:length(x)){
    if (i==1){
        v[i]<-x[i]
    }
    else{
        v[i]<-k*x[i]+(1-k)*v[i-1]
    }
}
return (v)
}
testOutput<-getEMA2(rnorm(100,0,1),5)
```

I've tried using the filter function, but it doesn't appear that recursive / convolution methods can achieve this

Thanks for responses,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `filter` computes

```
y[n] = x[n] + alpha * y[n-1]
```

you need to rescale the result.

```
f <- function(x,win) {
  alpha <- 2/(win+1)
  filter(x, 1-alpha, method="recursive", side=1, init=x[1]/alpha)*alpha
}
x <- 1:10
k <- 3
getEMA2(x,k)
f(x,k) # identical
```

Most of those filters are already defined in the `TTR` package.

Comment: +1, especially for beating me by a few minutes. :)  By the way, the `sides` argument only applies to convolution filters.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Joshua, I notice you've coded the TTR library. Why is it that EMA(1:10,2) produces output different from the getEMA2 function  I have posted above ? the EMA in the TTR package appears to be behaving like an SMA. i decided to post this thread in the first place because the TTR EMA is misbehaving for me.

Comment: @AdityaSihag: `TTR::EMA` seeds the exponential filter with the mean of the first `n` observations and sets the first `n-1` observations to `NA`. You can replicate it with: `filter(x[-(1:win)]*alpha, 1-alpha, method="recursive", init=mean(x[1:win]))`.